# Get list of subscribed group by user using ejabberd API

Tags: api, chat, ejabberd, multiuserchat

I am currently developing chat system for our application using ejabberd API.

I am having a problem on how to retrieve a list of subscribed group by username.

I only can retrieve a list of groups that user occupied, but not subscribed using get_room_users API.

My reference:
https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/

My question:

1. How to retrieve list of subscribed group by username?
2. Do I need to register all subscribers to the group to make use of get_room_users API?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. How to retrieve list of subscribed group by username?

There is no command to obtain that information.

> 2. Do I need to register all subscribers to the group to make use of get_room_users API?

I guess you mean get_room_occupants. Well, if you make the room subscribers also members of the room, then you can use get_room_affiliations, for example:

```
$ ejabberdctl get_room_affiliations room1 conference.localhost
user2   localhost       member
user1   localhost       owner
```

Comment: Hi Badlop, thank you for your reply.

I can retrieve all subscribers if I know the room name, but I need to retrieve by username only. But I already solved this problem few days after posted in here with different approach.

Comment: @MohamadRazimanMdDom can you share the approach you made? Im also have the same requirement